# How do you usually access bool, short, long, float and double in python array?

Tags: python, c, type-conversion, protocol-buffers

I have a message passed in from C to python using protobuf, the message is in the following format

```
messageMsg {

  repeated uint32 bool = 2 [packed=true];
  repeated uint32 short = 3 [packed=true];
  repeated uint32 long = 4 [packed=true];
  repeated uint32 float = 5 [packed=true];
  repeated uint32 double = 6 [packed=true];
   }
```

I want to be able to decode the data in python so here is what I did with int

```
    decoded_data = []
    for i in range(0, len(data)):
        raw_bytes = struct.pack('I', data[i]) #convert to raw bytes
        formatted_entry = struct.unpack("i", raw_bytes)[0] #convert to new format
        decoded_data.append(formatted_entry)
```

But now if I do that with short, long, double, bool, it would not work as each of those are not 32 bit.

```
# This does not work for double
for i in range(0, len(data)/2):
    raw_bytes = struct.pack('d', data[2*i:2*(i+1)]+) #convert to raw bytes

# This does not work for bool
for i in range(0, len(data)*4):
    raw_bytes = struct.pack("?", data[i/4:(i+1)/4])

# This does not work for short
etc...
```

Is there a way I can parse the uint32 into short, bool, and double?

Thanks

Comment: Are you trying to decode the protocol buffer yourself? You should be able to just use the classes generated by the protocol buffer compiler to do that.

Comment: How can a double fit in 32 bits when a double is 64 bits?